# Espacios blancos en los costados

Tags: css, design

Hola voy de nuevo con mis preguntas de novato en esto de programar y esta vez tengo la duda de porque si mi pagina es responsive y se supone que los fondos abarcan toda la pantalla, aún asi siempre quedan unos espacios blancos a los costados y no comprendo aún como hacer que tome todo el ancho sin dejar nada.

[image: Tamaño normal]
[image: Si hago mas grande la pantalla se adapta pero sin cosumir los bordes]

```
    .contenido{
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(24,168,107);
  background: linear-gradient(129deg, rgba(24,168,107,1) 0%, rgba(46,114,75,1) 100%);
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
    
    .contenido h2{
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .vid{
      padding: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      border-radius: 40px;
    }
    footer {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        padding: 2rem 8%;
        background-color: #0e0e0e;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
```

Comment: Agrega algo asi: `body{    margin:0; }` a ver

Comment: no amigo ya lo he intentado y nada

Comment: Siempre inicializa tu CSS con  *{ margin:0px; padding:0px; }, para eliminar los estilos por defecto.

Comment: Tambien diria que lo que tienes en `.contenido` lo pongos en `body` o sea body { ... }, lo que es el fondo, el tamaño porque segun veo .contenido debe ser un div y como en un div en fondo está solo en ese div y detras está el body

Comment: algo asi https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-sammet-xh6bxq?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: si puedo hacerla la cosa es que quiero que el body sea blanco y solo esa seccion tenga un gradient verde y ademas todos mis css inican con padding 0 y margin 0

Comment: Pero no quieres que se vea el blanco de atras? o sea que el div abarque toda la pantalla?

Comment: perdoname por no especificarlo tanto queiro que se extienda a lo ancho

Comment: Mira te paso de nuevo el link https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-sammet-xh6bxq?file=/src/styles.css es un div que cubre toda la pantalla ahi en el css puedes ir moviéndolos a tu conveniencia los margin, padding el height y el width,  a ver si te funciona asi

Comment: Perfecto, lo pude arreglar con tu ayuda, gracias

Comment: De nada, ya si quieres puedes contestar tu propia pregunta con lo que hiciste para solucionarlo como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto el  siempre tiene 8 píxeles de margin en su contorno. La solución a esto es agregando al css:

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

De todas formas, para descartar que fuese eso, nos vendría bien que nos facilitases también tu código HTML :)